# 404 NOT FOUND response on every HTTPS Ingress request

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have multiple Spring Boot applications deployed on GKE. Every Spring Boot has actuator endpoints enabled and unrestricted. I have created an HTTPS Ingress but I am getting only 404 Not Found responses.

Services overview:
[image]

Ingress YAML:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: mcrt-0c6bff90-d2fa-4a14-84b5-779c812a4c0b
    ingress.kubernetes.io/backends: '{"k8s-be-30206--3e15e15e4f605a79":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-31081--3e15e15e4f605a79":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-31129--3e15e15e4f605a79":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-31673--3e15e15e4f605a79":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-32006--3e15e15e4f605a79":"HEALTHY"}'
    ingress.kubernetes.io/https-forwarding-rule: k8s-fws-default-skitter-ingress--3e15e15e4f605a79
    ingress.kubernetes.io/https-target-proxy: k8s-tps-default-skitter-ingress--3e15e15e4f605a79
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-cert: mcrt-0c6bff90-d2fa-4a14-84b5-779c812a4c0b
    ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: k8s-um-default-skitter-ingress--3e15e15e4f605a79
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http":"false","kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name":"skitter-ip","networking.gke.io/managed-certificates":"skitterapp.com"},"name":"skitter-ingress","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"skitterapp.com","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"business-owner-service","servicePort":80},"path":"/business-owner-service/*"},{"backend":{"serviceName":"customer-service","servicePort":80},"path":"/customer-service/*"},{"backend":{"serviceName":"staff-service","servicePort":80},"path":"/staff-service/*"},{"backend":{"serviceName":"sms-service","servicePort":80},"path":"/sms-service/*"}]}}]}}
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: skitter-ip
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: skitterapp.com
  creationTimestamp: "2020-09-20T12:10:35Z"
  finalizers:
  - networking.gke.io/ingress-finalizer
  generation: 3
  name: skitter-ingress
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "11344191"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/skitter-ingress
  uid: 6b92ff0d-01a2-449f-9cd7-afdd1452e73b
spec:
  rules:
  - host: skitterapp.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: business-owner-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /business-owner-service/*
      - backend:
          serviceName: customer-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /customer-service/*
      - backend:
          serviceName: staff-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /staff-service/*
      - backend:
          serviceName: sms-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /sms-service/*
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 35.241.60.223
```

Load balancer details (to highlight certificate is active and everything seems in order):
[image]

Test requests: https://skitterapp.com/business-owner-service/actuator/health ;
https://skitterapp.com/customer-service/actuator/health

Log is not very helpful:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? I expect that when I send a request skitterapp.com/customer-service/actuator/health, the ingress identifies /customer-service/**, and passes the GET request /actuator/health to the customer service. But I am not seeing this behaviour and from what I see in the logs, customer service is not receiving the health request

Comment: Is there any rest controller serving at this path for example  `/business-owner-service` ? Check the logs of the ingress controller pods. Last time I checked GKE ingress does not support `rewrite-target` like nginx ingress controller does

Comment: You are asking of the business-owner-service because it is the default service and maybe every request get sent to the default rule? There are no requests under /business-owner-service

Comment: Unless you do rewrite target the request will be send to that path of that application instead of root path. https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/109

Comment: " will be send to that path of that application instead of root path" can you please give me an example?

Comment: What I think ArghyaSadhu was telling is that if you were to send a query like following: `skitterapp.com/customer-service/hello` it would arrive to the pod with `/customer-service/hello`. With rewrite it could be only `hello`. What `URL` are needed to be present at your pods for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this annotation in the ingress,

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /

may be this can solve the issue